# Automatically update import path if file is moved in Vim

Tags: filetype-python, path

Is there a way in which if you move file A to another location and there are other files that have imported file A, the import path will change accordingly in Vim?

PyCharm has this and I was wondering if this could be implemented for Vim. An example written in Python:

main.py

```
from projects.scripts import file_a
```

I then move file_a.py to projects/final. If I'm using PyCharm, main.py will be updated with the new import path

main.py

```
from projects.final import file_a
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid vim can't listen for files moved.

What you can do is to check how Eunuch plugin works regarding moving files, then you'll need to search for all files that import the moved one, and to update them.

You could also provide a service "ModePythonFile" built on top of Eunuch.